# Custom post type custom taxonomy not found

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post type on my site called Homes, which is working correctly. I created a custom taxonomy to go with it named Availability Category, and a category within that named Available Now. The taxonomy shows up in my Wordpress back end, but when I go view the category at homes/available-now, I get a 404 error.

Here is the code for my custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'Homes',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Homes' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Homes Item' ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Homes Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Homes Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New Homes Item'),
        ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies' => array('homes-category'),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'        => TRUE,
        'rewrite' => array( 
            'slug' => 'homes',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,

            ),
    )
);
```

And the code for my custom taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'homes-category',
    'homes',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => __( 'Availability Category' ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'homes',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
    )
);
```

Can anyone help with this? I've searched for hours for a fix and nothing I have tried so far has worked. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have assigned the same rewrite slug for the custom post type "homes" as the taxonomy "homes-category".

To fix your problem, simply change your code for registering the custom post type to this:

```
register_post_type( 'Homes',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Homes' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Homes Item' ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Homes Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Homes Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New Homes Item'),
        ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies' => array('homes-category'),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'        => TRUE,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'home', //remove the "s" so that it's not fighting with Taxonomy
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,

            ),
    )
);
```

Then revisit your Permalink page, and try again.  What's good now, is that you also regain the ability to create a Page called "homes" again, with which you could create a custom template for.  I've tested all of this and it works.  :)

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but am still getting a 404 when I go to homes/available-now.

Comment: Did you assign a home to the "available-now" taxonomy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by assigning a home to the "available-now" taxonomy. I did figure out that if I put the register taxonomy code above the custom post type code, it works.

Comment: Strange, because in my Functions.php I had it ordered exactly how you had it originally.  What I meant was, within your newly created custom post type, did you select the taxonomy before publishing it.

Comment: Moving the taxonomy above the custom post type worked initially, but I've realized that doing that isn't going to accomplish what I need it to do.

And yes, I selected the taxonomy before publishing.

Comment: is your .htaccess file able to be written to by WordPress?

Comment: Yes, my .htaccess file is able to be written to by Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing your permalinks by simply visiting **WP Admin > Settings > Permalinks**

Now see if you still get the 404..

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried this numerous times and I still get a 404. If I set the permalinks to default, the page works though. I only get the 404 when they are set to post name.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any conflicting pages / posts using the same slug (ie:  did you create a page with the name "homes"?).   If you did, delete them and be sure to empty the trash as well.

Comment: I did have a page named homes. I deleted it and emptied it from the trash, but I am still getting the 404 error.

Comment: Did you revisit the Permalinks settings again after doing this?

Comment: Yup. I even set it to default, then back to post type and am still getting a 404. I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. I did a custom post type "products" and custom taxonomy "products" and that cost me an 404 error when i was trying to reach www.domain.com/products. The address www.domain.com/products/product-01 was ok.

So you have to rename your custom post type to "product" and the CTP to "products" so they are different. First delete the custom post type and the custom taxonomy. Then register your new CPT and CTP
with DIFFERENT names !!!

CPT - custom post type
CTP - custom taxonomy type